# Trying to print amount of recieved emails from a specific email adress

Tags: python, analysis, exchangelib

I'm working with some code in python with the exchangelib library, I'm trying to print a list of specific email addresses with a counter that counts the amount of emails recieved from that emailaddress. This is my code, but I'm not getting any printed output.

```
from exchangelib import Credentials, Account
from collections import defaultdict

emails = ['email1@example.com','email2@example.dk']
credentials = Credentials('random@user.dk', 'Brute')
account = Account('random@user.dk', credentials=credentials, autodiscover=True)




def count_senders(emails):
    counts = defaultdict(int)
    for email in emails:
        counts[email.sender.email_address] += 1
    return counts
    print(counts)
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Lines after `return` in a function aren't executed because the execution has already been returned to where the function was called from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see your function call in the code. Maybe that is the problem?

```
count_senders(emails)
```

Other problem is that you are printing after the **return** which doesn't work. Change your function order like this:

```
def count_senders(emails):
    counts = defaultdict(int)
    for email in emails:
        counts[item.sender.email_address] += 1
    print(counts)
    return counts
```

Update:
**Try to put your real email and credentials before running the code.**

```
emails = ['email1@example.com','email2@example.dk']

for email in emails:
    credentials = Credentials(email, 'Brute')
    account = Account(email, credentials=credentials, autodiscover=True)
    counts = defaultdict(int)
    for item in account.inbox.all().order_by('-datetime_received')[:100]:
        print(item.subject, item.sender, item.datetime_received)
        counts[email.sender.email_address] += 1
    print(counts)
```

Comment: Still no output :/

Comment: @FarzadHenareh check my answer once again.

Comment: I tried what you suggested again, but still nothing is being output.

Comment: Is it because I haven't chosen the mailbox that I want it to iterate through? @SamL

Comment: your loop doesn't make a sense. Try this and tell me what you get: 
for item in account.inbox.all().order_by('-datetime_received')[:100]:
    print(item.subject, item.sender, item.datetime_received)

Comment: I tried and it gave me lots of emails with subjects, time it was recieved and such. That loop worked

Comment: What's your goal? to loop through the list of emails and create an account for each? And do looping... if so, then you are doing it wrong

Comment: Loop through the list of email-adresses and count the amount of emails gotten from those email-adresses.

Comment: printedoutput = {example@example.com, 27}

Comment: check it once again and tell me what you get

Comment: It worked however, I changed this line counts[email.sender.email_address] += 1 to counts[**item**.sender.email_address] += 1

Comment: It's printing the numbers found, but also for some other email-adresses that I didn't choose. How can I limit it to the ones I've specified in the list only? @SamL

Comment: @FarzadHenareh Please edit your question instead of adding comments; people may not see your comments here, and comment order is not chronologically but by votes, making this hard to read.